# Gmod SRCDS, sound errors on startup?

Tags: server-administration, garrys-mod

Whenever I start up my Gmod13 server without any addons/gamemodes and after running the update tool, I always get this error:

```
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_portal.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_player _portal.txt CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_weapon s_episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_weapon s_portal.txt CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_music _portal.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_escap e.txt 
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_apertur e_ai.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_energy_ ball.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_turret_ portal.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_rocket_ turret.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_glados_ cores.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_strider _episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_turret_ episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_soldier _episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_roller_ episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_combine _ball_episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_citizen _episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_citizen _ep1.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_zombine .txt 
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_dog_epi sodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_antlion guard_episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/npc_sounds_advisor .txt 
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_e3_c1 7.txt 
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_e3_to wn.txt 
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_e3_bu gbait.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_music _episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_voices_episo de_01.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_after math_episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_outla nd_episodic.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/level_sounds_c17_0 2a.txt 
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_mvm.tx t 
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_vo.txt  
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_vo_mvm .txt 
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_vo_mvm _handmade.txt
    CSoundEmitterSystem::AddSoundsFromFile:  No such file scripts/game_sounds_vo_mvm _mighty.txt
```

I can still connect, although I'd rather solve this now, as errors are there for a reason. Google has turned up no results that hold a viable solution, as this happens vanilla. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the log, it looks like it's trying to pull audio from other Sourcegames(Portal, HL2, and TF2 are the ones that stick out to me) and use it with the in game "Sound Emitter" tool. If you want to try and fix the errors, you could try following this link(http://forums.srcds.com/viewtopic/13138), which details how to copy over content from other source games on to a dedicated server. Otherwise the errors are safe to ignore, as they're just warnings that you can't use those sounds with Sound Emitter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like its trying to use sounds from Half-Life that you do not have installed in your server. I often get errors like this and the game runs fine, there are just some sounds that the server will not trigger and in turn all clients cannot hear.  It isn't anything to worry too much about.